# How to make hdparm settings survive reboot?

Tags: hard-drive, sleep, reboot, suspend, hdparm

`hdparm` settings are lost after reboot. How to setup

```
hdparm -B60 /dev/sda
```

to be saved for the next reboot?

Answer (score 3):

The most primitive approach is to put the `hdparm -B60 /dev/sda` command into `/etc/rc.local`. If you use `systemd` then you should see this: [*What is the correct substitute for `rc.local` in `systemd` instead of re-creating `rc.local`?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/471824/108618)

**But** some distros (at least Debian and its derivatives) use `/etc/hdparm.conf` file. In my Debian `man 5 hdparm.conf` says

> This  is the default configuration for `hdparm` for Debian.  It is a rather simple script, [...]
>
> Setting an option outside of one of the stanzas enables it for all drives.
>
> If an option is listed twice, the second instance replaces the first.
>
> `/sbin/hdparm` is not run unless a block of the form:
>
> ```
>   DEV {
>   option
>   option
>   }
> ```
>
> exists.  This blocks will cause `/sbin/hdparm OPTIONS DEV` to be run.  Where `OPTIONS` is the concatenation of all options previously defined outside of a block and all options defined with in the block.
>
> [...]
>
> OPTIONS
>
> [...]
>
> `-B` apm setting
> `apm = 255`

One should also read comments in the `/etc/hdparm.conf` file itself; and the entire `/usr/share/doc/hdparm/README.Debian` (the file may be gzipped, extract it).

I think the following block in the configuration file will recreate your command (`hdparm -B60 /dev/sda`) on startup:

```
/dev/sda {
apm = 60
}
```

Comment: Don't need to extract gzipped docs, "zless" will probably do.